# Cant connect to Firebase database using URL

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-volley

I am trying to connect my application to a cloud database, but I always get an error response and I don't know what's the error I'm getting, I'm still new at Android development and this is my code for connecting to my online database, which is Firebase:

```
private void connectServer(){

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    String url = "https://rabaapps.firebaseio.com/";
    Log.e("url", url);

    mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();


    final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
            url, new JSONObject(), this, this);


    mQueue.add(jsonRequest);

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Volley to read data from Firebase. I recommend you use the new [Firebase Android SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) as it provides better methods to handle requests.

Comment: Firebase data may be stored similar to JSON, but you should compile the Firebase database dependencies and use those correctly.

Comment: thank you for the great help, the sdk did it all